# Repository can't be injected when using Spring Data JPA with pure Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am learning using Spring Data to access my MySQL database. Since I am new to Spring and not using Spring Boot, I failed to find useful tutorial.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id('io.spring.dependency-management') version('1.0.3.RELEASE')
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.10'
}

group 'com.perqin'
version '1.0.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Ingalls-SR6'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.7-dmr'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.6.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.10.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

And here is my persistence config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.perqin.focus.spring.domain.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Driver.class.getName());
        dataSource.setUsername("perqin");
        dataSource.setPassword("dev123456");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/focus_spring?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(EntityScanned.class.getPackage().toString());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");  // MySQL5InnoDBDialect   MySQLMyISAMDialect
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
}

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");  // MySQL5InnoDBDialect   MySQLMyISAMDialect
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

But after starting the app, I get such output:

```
10:27:07 PM: Executing external task 'appRun'...
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder
:createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses
:prepareInplaceWebApp
:appRun
22:27:10 INFO  2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
22:27:10 INFO  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22:27:11 WARN  Failed startup of context o.a.g.JettyWebAppContext@db57326{/focus.spring,file:/home/perqin/workspaces/Focus/Focus-Server-Spring/build/inplaceWebapp/,STARTING}
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.perqin.focus.spring.domain.repositories.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800) ~[jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.super$10$doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy) [gretty-runner-jetty9-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-jetty9-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle$start$0.call(Unknown Source) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:45) [gretty-runner-jetty-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:117) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.perqin.focus.spring.domain.repositories.UsersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[na:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
22:27:11 INFO  Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606 started and listening on port 8080
22:27:11 INFO  focus.spring runs at:
22:27:11 INFO    http://localhost:8080/focus.spring
Press any key to stop the server.
```

I've referred to many example code, but I can't find any difference that matters.

For reference, here's the source code: https://github.com/perqin/Focus-Server-Spring

Comment: Why are you not using Boot?

Comment: try register PersistenceJpaConfig in WebInitializer

Comment: @chrylis As I am new to Spring, Spring Boot does too much encapsulation and abstraction, so it is a little difficult for me:(

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko Hey you save my day! After register PersistenceJpaConfig in WebInitializer and correct the entity package name to be scanned (well, another mistake made by me) the app boots without any error. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you scanning the beans?